# Are there any major benefits to installing the GUI for Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, gui

I'm a complete newbie to Linux/Ubuntu but have (after following many online guides and looking through many forums) now managed to get my Ubuntu home server up and running. It is an old Fujitsu Siemens desktop that my parents had lying around and I thought I would use it as my own "test unit" and practise setting up as a server. I actually do not intend to use this particular machine as a long-term home server but thought I'd be better off making mistakes with this before upgrading to a more modern machine.

Along my travels across these guides and forums, I saw the GUI mentioned - and that others had installed this to their server but I am just curious to get a wider perspective on the use of a GUI with a server. **Is there any need for one?** **What benefits would it bring by using one?**

I'm quite happy learning my way through the Terminal inputs but would just like to cover as many options as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I like to keep my servers as "thin" as possible; more code, more tools, more stuff is more attack surface.  Yes, the GUI (X) doesn't need to run all the time; but I don't need all those dependencies installed either.

The one upside I've found is that I can run a headless Chrome browser for some automation and crawling bots.

Answer (score 1):

A graphical desktop such as gnome, kde, xfce, etc add very little if anything over ssh in server management as desktop tasks are not the same as server tasks.

If you want a graphical environment for server management use a web solution such as webmin or cockpit http://cockpit-project.org/ or phpmyadmin or  openstack or ...